# Google Sheet API, PUT: this.http.put(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make a simple `PUT` call to google sheets API. I followed some of the `http.put` syntax, but keep getting the error: `this.http.put(...).map is not a function.`

My code block:

```
return this.http
           .put(url, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
           .map(
                (res: any) => {
                   res.json();
                   console.log ("transaction data updated to google seets:"+res.json());
                }
           );
```

Comment: Where did you get the `http.put` syntax from?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I was searching this site and got the syntax from one of the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420078/angular-4-0-http-put-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import ?

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**EDIT**

You need to import the above, also i would recommend you to use HttpClient instead of HttpModule which would remove the res.json(), your code will look like,

set the options as,

```
return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(formData), this.options)
.pipe(map(response => response.json()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using HTTPClient Module?. Here is the Way of Performing PUT method which is similar to POST method.

```
return this.http.put<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, data, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(res => {
         console.log(res);
         return res;
      },
      catchError(this.handleError('updateHero', hero))
    );
```

Comment: .pipe(map(..)) made the error go away, I'm still getting 401 though, but that's a different error and I think I can work that out. Thanks